# How to "Automatically" test my Entity without .vwf/.bdf files

Tags: automated-tests, vhdl, quartus

I am writing in VHDL (**at Quartus II Web Edition [Software v9.1 Service Pack 2]**) for a project of mine and I encountered a problem.

I have created a large decoder which I would like to test but **no**t via creating a .bdf file and then adding a vector waveform file on it.

For the needs of this testing I have made a Python script to create .txt files with the proper 32bit vectors on it and then I am inserting them (c/p) to the .vwf file. Finally I do a timing simulation and then observe the outputs if they are the correct ones or not...but this is really time consuming and I think there is probably a better way to do it.

Or should I add the pain of converting by hand the 32bit values to integers to see that they are the ones expected after testing.

So, is there a faster/easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a VHDL testbench. This can be used to drive your DUT (design under test) however you want. There a plenty of tutorials and training courses out on the web, with some even provided by intel. BTW, Quartus 9.1 is 10 years old. Is there any reason you are not using a more up to date version?

Comment: It was given freely to us...hence that's what we've learned to use at the University. I am sure there are no such big differences with the newest versions, (It will be easy to learn them I mean) but since I know how to use the old version good, I am sticking with it till the deadline !

Ontopic: I know about the Benchmarking but I haven't really created one. I guess I will look it up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Adding to @Tricky 's point I think the VHDL Testbench is the way to go with this question (even though you dont want to write it). VHDL has a std.textio and IEEE.std_logic_textio package which will allow you to write in the .txt files you have made with python (with ease, I might add). [NANDLAND](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-file-io.html) has a really good tutorial on this, which I would advise you to check out.